# Smart rolling window in pandas groupby rolling

Tags: pandas, window, rolling-computation

I have dataframe with orders delivering data like this:

```
    order_num   supplier    order_date  delivering_date_plan    delivering_date_fact    not_delivered_in_time
0   1           supplier_1  2023-01-01  2023-01-04              2023-01-04              0
1   2           supplier_2  2023-01-02  2023-01-04              2023-01-06              1
2   3           supplier_1  2023-01-03  2023-01-09              2023-01-11              1
3   4           supplier_1  2023-01-04  2023-01-14              2023-01-14              0
4   5           supplier_2  2023-01-05  2023-01-09              2023-01-07              0
5   6           supplier_2  2023-01-06  2023-01-14              2023-01-17              1
6   7           supplier_1  2023-01-07  2023-01-19              2023-01-22              1
7   8           supplier_1  2023-01-08  2023-01-24              2023-01-25              1
8   9           supplier_1  2023-01-09  2023-01-29              2023-01-30              1
9   10          supplier_2  2023-01-10  2023-01-19              2023-01-17              0
```

and **I wanna calculate for each supplier how many orders they didn't deliver in plan date (at the moment of  the order_date)**.

I use:

```
df['last_10d_nondeliverings'] = df.groupby('supplier').apply(lambda x: x.rolling('10D', on='order_date', closed= "left").sum())['not_delivered_in_time']
```

it shows me:

```
    order_num   supplier    order_date  delivering_date_plan    delivering_date_fact    not_delivered_in_time   last_10d_nondeliverings
0   1           supplier_1  2023-01-01  2023-01-04              2023-01-04              0                       NaN
1   2           supplier_2  2023-01-02  2023-01-04              2023-01-06              1                       NaN
2   3           supplier_1  2023-01-03  2023-01-09              2023-01-11              1                       0.0
3   4           supplier_1  2023-01-04  2023-01-14              2023-01-14              0                       1.0
4   5           supplier_2  2023-01-05  2023-01-09              2023-01-07              0                       1.0
5   6           supplier_2  2023-01-06  2023-01-14              2023-01-17              1                       1.0
6   7           supplier_1  2023-01-07  2023-01-19              2023-01-22              1                       1.0
7   8           supplier_1  2023-01-08  2023-01-24              2023-01-25              1                       2.0
8   9           supplier_1  2023-01-09  2023-01-29              2023-01-30              1                       3.0
9   10          supplier_2  2023-01-10  2023-01-19              2023-01-17              0                       2.0
```

but I need this (look at the the last column):

```
    order_num   supplier    order_date  delivering_date_plan    delivering_date_fact    not_delivered_in_time   last_10d_nondeliverings
0   1           supplier_1  2023-01-01  2023-01-04              2023-01-04              0                       NaN
1   2           supplier_2  2023-01-02  2023-01-04              2023-01-06              1                       NaN
2   3           supplier_1  2023-01-03  2023-01-09              2023-01-11              1                       0.0
3   4           supplier_1  2023-01-04  2023-01-14              2023-01-14              0                       0.0
4   5           supplier_2  2023-01-05  2023-01-09              2023-01-07              0                       0.0
5   6           supplier_2  2023-01-06  2023-01-14              2023-01-17              1                       1.0
6   7           supplier_1  2023-01-07  2023-01-19              2023-01-22              1                       0.0
7   8           supplier_1  2023-01-08  2023-01-24              2023-01-25              1                       0.0
8   9           supplier_1  2023-01-09  2023-01-29              2023-01-30              1                       0.0
9   10          supplier_2  2023-01-10  2023-01-19              2023-01-17              0                       1.0
```

So, how to calculate rolling sum, considering only orders which have `delivering_date_fact` EQUAL or LOWER than `order_date` for each order?

Comment: Could you double-check the expected values are correct? E.g. on `2023-01-05`, none of `supplier_2`'s orders have `delivering_date_fact` ≤ their `order_date`, so why is it expected that `last_10d_nondeliverings` be `1.0` in this case?

Comment: You are right, first expected `1.0` for `supplier_2` should be on `2023-01-06`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, lets create a reproducible example:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=[
        "order_num",
        "supplier",
        "order_date",
        "delivering_date_plan",
        "delivering_date_fact",
        "not_delivered_in_time",
    ],
    data=[
        [1, "supplier_1", "2023-01-01", "2023-01-04", "2023-01-04", 0],
        [2, "supplier_2", "2023-01-02", "2023-01-04", "2023-01-06", 1],
        [3, "supplier_1", "2023-01-03", "2023-01-09", "2023-01-11", 1],
        [4, "supplier_1", "2023-01-04", "2023-01-14", "2023-01-14", 0],
        [5, "supplier_2", "2023-01-05", "2023-01-09", "2023-01-07", 0],
        [6, "supplier_2", "2023-01-06", "2023-01-14", "2023-01-17", 1],
        [7, "supplier_1", "2023-01-07", "2023-01-19", "2023-01-22", 1],
        [8, "supplier_1", "2023-01-08", "2023-01-24", "2023-01-25", 1],
        [9, "supplier_1", "2023-01-09", "2023-01-29", "2023-01-30", 1],
        [10, "supplier_2", "2023-01-10", "2023-01-19", "2023-01-17", 0],
    ],
)\
.astype(
    {
        "order_date": "datetime64",
        "delivering_date_plan": "datetime64",
        "delivering_date_fact": "datetime64",
    }
)
```

For each order of each supplier, we want to count how many orders from the 10 days prior before the `order_date` were `not_delivered_in_time`, according to what was known at that time. For convenience, let's set the index to this `order_date` field that is used as reference:

```py
df.set_index("order_date", inplace=True)
```

We only knew that an order was late at a given date if its `delivering_date_plan` had arrived. Therefore, let's require that the `delivering_date_plan` is less than or equal to the reference date before counting:

```py
def window_count(group) -> pd.Series:
    def late_order_count(is_late):
        order_date = is_late.index[-1]
        was_late = group.loc[is_late.index, "delivering_date_plan"] <= order_date
        return (is_late.astype(bool) & was_late).sum()

    return group.rolling("10D", closed="left")["not_delivered_in_time"].apply(
        late_order_count
    )


df["last_10d_nondeliverings"] = (
    df.groupby("supplier").apply(window_count).droplevel("supplier").sort_index()
)
print(df[["last_10d_nondeliverings"]])
```

which results in

```
            last_10d_nondeliverings
order_date                         
2023-01-01                      NaN
2023-01-02                      NaN
2023-01-03                      0.0
2023-01-04                      0.0
2023-01-05                      0.0
2023-01-06                      1.0
2023-01-07                      0.0
2023-01-08                      0.0
2023-01-09                      0.0
2023-01-10                      1.0
```

Comment: thank you so much! But it seems like 10D window doesn't include orders which should be delivered in last 10D AND which created 10D+ before current order created. How can we fix this?